# S3EncryptionClient (not async) Unable to execute HTTP request: headersFuture is still not completed when onStream() is invoked

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

We are migrating to the latest versions (2.24.5) of aws-sdk and amazon-s3-encryption-client-java
The code where I create S3EncryptionClient and call it (3.1.1 library version)
I want to read the S3 object but I have the exception

```
  private S3EncryptionClient getEncryptionClient(String regionName, KeyPair keyPair) {
        return S3EncryptionClient.builder()
                .rsaKeyPair(keyPair)
                .enableDelayedAuthenticationMode(true)
                .enableLegacyUnauthenticatedModes(true)
                .enableLegacyWrappingAlgorithms(true)
                .wrappedClient(getClient(regionName))
                .wrappedAsyncClient(getAsyncClient(regionName))
                .build();
    }
    ..
        private ClientOverrideConfiguration createClientConfiguration() {
        return S3Client.builder()
                .httpClient(
                        ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                                .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(clientConnectionTimeout))
                                .build())
                .overrideConfiguration()
                .toBuilder()
                .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(NUM_RETRIES).build())
                .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(clientRequestTimeout))
                .build();
    }
...
...
     s3Client.getObject(getGetObjectRequest(storageKey)), isZip;
 ...
```

The error I see:

````
Caused by: sotware.amazon.encryption.s3.S3EncryptionClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: headersFuture is still not completed when onStream() is invoked.
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.encryption.s3.S3EncryptionClient.getObject(S3EncryptionClient.java:255)
    
    Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: headersFuture is still not completed when onStream() is invoked.
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:218)
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:182)
    at deployment.fs.war//software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.lambda$attemptExecute$1(AsyncRetryableStage.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)

    ```

Why do I see something about the future if I do not use an async client?
How can I correctly get the response and use InputStream here? I cant see any wait/join function to wait.
````

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-s3-encryption-client-java/issues/186

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see this strange error, maybe it means that you are trying to get an unecrypted object with an Encrypted Client.
In my case it helps

Previously (in the v1 of was SDK) it was
Unable to detect encryption information for object 'key' in bucket 'bucket'. Returning object without decryption.